# Django query, greater than and lower than are not working

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following table:

```
class OverallAdvise(mixins.OrdMixin, mixins.EqMixin, models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey('quest.Section',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='section_owner')
    range_start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    range_end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    get_advise = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Then, in serializer I'm trying to select the `get_advise` based on a calculated score.

My query is:

```
get_overall_advise = OverallAdvise.objects.filter(section_id = section_id, range_start__gte = section_overall_score, range_end__lte = section_overall_score).values("get_advise")
```

but it's not working.

When I use only `section_id` in my query, it's working.

`section_id=6` and `section_overall_score=8` are given.

I need something like `range_start<=6<=range_end`.

This is an instance of my `mysql` table: [image]

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you tell me `range_start__gte = section_overall_score, range_end__lte = section_overall_score` what is this logic? you want to select only 8 section_overall_score according your logic.

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I want to have something like : `range_start<=6<=range_end`

Comment: But you'll not get output according to your logic. Update code as below 
`range_start__lte = section_overall_score, range_end__gte = section_overall_score`

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR Thank you! The example is working if `section_overall_score` is in range `0,12`. If the score is higher I still get error. Even though the range values are stored in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `mysql` example, I see that range_start is never greater than range_end, so `range_start__gte=value` and `range_end__lte=value` won't match any entry since value is the same. Except maybe range_start == range_end == value

So if you want `range_start <= 6 <= range_end` you should use `range_start__lte=6, range_end__gte=6`

Comment: When I use only `section_id` in my query, it's working.

Comment: Ok didn't know that worked. Please see my edited answer then

Comment: I want to have something like :  `range_start<=6<=range_end`

Comment: Then it should be `range_start__lte=6, range_end__gte=6` for range_start is less than or equal and range_end is greater than or equal

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Add it in your answer to accept it!

Comment: Thank you! The example is working if  `section_overall_score` is in range 0,12. If the score is higher I still get error.

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting ? Or is it just that you have no match ?

Comment: I'm using a `rest api` call and I get `HTTP/1.1 500` so I guess it's a no match error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165968/discussion-between-gabriel-samain-and-zinon).

Answer (score 0):

When writing you ORM query as if statements you will see the error

```
for row in OverallAdvise.objects.all():
    if row.section_id == section_id:
        if range_start >= section_overall_score:
            if range_end <= section_overall_score:
                return row.get_advice
```

This will never be successful as `range_start` <= `range_end`. I think you wanted to switch `lte` and `gte` around in your query.

```
get_overall_advise = OverallAdvise.objects.filter(section_id = section_id, range_start__lte = section_overall_score, range_end__gte = section_overall_score).values("get_advise")
```

Comment: This is only working for `section_overall_score` = 0-12. If  for example `section_overall_score` =16 I still get `http 500` error.

Comment: And what is the error. The error could also not be related to this. Please add the error to the original post if applicable.